# How to add two gridviews in single update panel in web form

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have used update panel while designing web form.How to add two gridviews side by side in single update panel.I am trying to add it but it adds another one underneath the original one.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide them in two divs.
Set the "display" to "inline-block" and adjust the width to your needing (maybe 50% each)

```
<YOUR PARENT/UPDATE PANEL/ETC>
     <div>
          <div style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">
               <asp:GridView runat="server" id="grv1" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
               </asp:GridView>
          </div>
          <div style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">
               <asp:GridView runat="server" id="grv2" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
               </asp:GridView>
          </div>
     </div>
</YOUR PARENT/UPDATE PANEL/ETC>
```